# Did Gellert Grindelwald actually die in the movies?

Tags: harry-potter, gellert-grindelwald

Reading *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, it is mentioned that Grindelwald refused to reveal the location and who truly possessed the Elder Wand, thus getting killed by Voldemort.

However, in the movie (which I have watched again for leisure), it is observed that Grindelwald did in fact divulge the whereabouts of the Elder Wand, as can be seen here:

He did not get killed by Voldemort.  In this case, the book doesn't seem to tie in with the movie, and the movie leaves me with doubt as to how Grindelwald was indeed killed.

To clarify, I would like to know why Grindelwald is never portrayed to be killed by Voldemort in the movies.

Comment: It would appear not, at least not be Voldemort anyway. I'll try and find something more concrete but ?I can't find any mention of him being killed in the films

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yeah, but this means its different from the book?

Comment: Look "close" enough and the films are quite different... in some regards anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot okay, thanks for that.  But for now book and movie don't seem to align, even for others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Grindelwald was never depicted as having died in the movies.

Though the Dark Lord kills him in the book, in the movie, Grindelwald seems to remain alive. The last time Grindelwald is seen or mentioned is when the Dark Lord goes to him to find out where the Elder Wand is. Unlike in the book, where Grindelwald refuses to tell the Dark Lord anything, he does give the Dark Lord the information he wanted, and says it’s buried with Dumbledore.

> 158 INT. CELL - CONTINUOUS ACTION - NIGHT
>
> ... finds a SKELETAL FIGURE lying beneath a ragged blanket. The figure stirs, looks up, and grins with broken teeth. It is the young man -- the thief -- grown old. Grindelwald.
>
> GRINDELWALD
>   
> *Ah, Tom, I thought you would come one day. But surely you must know I no longer have what you seek...*
>
> A SHADOW -- Voldemort’s -- falls across Grindelwald.
>
> VOLDEMORT 
>   
> If not you, then who?
>
> GRINDELWALD
>   
> *You’re so innocent, Tom. Like a schoolboy. There’s so much you don’t understand...*
>
> VOLDEMORT
>   
> *Tell me, Grindelwald. Tell me where to find it! Tell me who possesses it! The name, Grindelwald! The name!*
>
> GRINDELWALD 
>   
> Can’t you guess, Tom? It lies
>   with him, of course. Buried within the earth. It is he who possesses it, even in death. Your old friend and mine... Dumbledore. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part One (Screenplay)](http://www.gazette-du-sorcier.com/IMG/pdf/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows_-_Part_1.pdf)*</sup></sub>

After that, Grindelwald isn’t mentioned again, and since the Dark Lord isn’t shown as having killed him and would have no reason to, presumably Grindelwald remained alive in Nurmengard.

Answer (score -2):

In the movie, there appears to be a scene where a dark wizard comes charging through one of the castle windows during the attack on Hogwarts. The wizard is frozen for a moment and then driven back through the window to his possible death. This wizard looks like Grindelwald. The director freezes the wizard so we can clearly see him, and it looks to me to be Grindelwald, so I believe he dies at that point in the movies, while in the books, Voldemort kills him.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This feels quite tenuous. Can you provide any evidence that the wizard was intended to be Grindelwald? Perhaps a visual comparison of Grindelwald as he appears in Part 1, and the wizard shown charging through the window?

Comment: You appear to be describing the scene in the question and the one spelled out in [the other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/199402/58193). That scene, however, is quite ambiguous in its approach to the events. Do you have any evidence beyond it and your own belief that Voldemort does indeed kill him? If so you should [edit] that into your answer.